# Poor speakers quality on lenovo thinkpad e460 with Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, sound, lenovo, thinkpad, soundcard

I've just installed Ubuntu 16.04 LTS on my laptop Lenovo ThinkPad E460. Everything works fine, expect speakers, the loudness is all right, but the quality is really poor, I don't know how to explain this, it's really cracky, On Windows 10 it sounds way better. This particular model has Conexant audio card, which has drivers only for Windows. So, the question is, how to improve my speakers quality? Thanks :)

EDIT. 
I forgot to say, the sound quality on headphones is great, same as on Windows 10

Comment: yes I've this problem too, but when tying to live boot from usb the sounds is great, but after updateing the soungs quality and the volume is down

Answer (score 0):

I am facing similar problem on L450. But my problem is more with recording. Whatever I record has lot of noise. But on windows it works perfectly fine. Don't know what is the issue.

Comment: this is a comment not an answer mate!

Answer (score 0):

The T460S comes with some kind of Dolby Sound Software, which makes audio quality **significantly** better. If you turn that software off, audio quality is the same on Windows and Ubuntu.